# Serializing a CGContext

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

How does one serialize a CGContext that contains a modified CGMutablePathRef?

I currently save the context into png representation and serialize this, but it is causing issues with retina display.

I would like to avoid serializing a retina version and resizing it at runtime as this would be inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just stroking or filling a single path, you can wrap it in a `UIBezierPath`, which conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, and then you can serialize the `UIBezierPath`:

```
UIBezierPath *uiPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:cgPath];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:uiPath];
```

Then you can write `data` to a file or your database or whatever.  Later you can convert `data` back to a `UIBezierPath` and then a `CGPath`:

```
UIBezierPath *uiPath = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
CGPathRef cgPath = uiPath.CGPath;
```

If you are drawing something more complex than a single path, the easiest way to serialize your drawing in a scalable (vector) format is to draw to a `CGPDFContext` instead of a `CGBitmapContext`.  A `CGPDFContext` records your drawing commands to a PDF.  Later, you can create a `CGPDFDocument` for the PDF, and use that to draw the PDF to your bitmap context.  Read the [PDF Document Creation, Viewing, and Transforming chapter of the * Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) for details.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at this. I am adding a gradient to fill the path.